# Get an element from an array at an index a user specified

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I want to build a function that takes two inputs:

1. an array of arrays
2. index number

and then returns an array inside the input array that it located at the input index.

The following is the code I got so far.

So, if a user calls the function with the following inputs, the expected result is [4,5,6] .

```js
const input = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
];

const index = 1;

function grab(input, index) {
  var result = [];

  return result = input[index];
  console.log(result);
};
```

Comment: Do you want to return 1) the array at that index, or 2) a copy of that array? For example, if you return the array, assign it to a variable, and then change it (`const arr = grab(input, index); arr.push(10);`, for example) would you expect the array in `input` to also change?

Comment: `grab` shouldn't need to exist... you can just do `input[index]` or `[...input[index]]`.

Comment: I think I was initially thinking to 'copy' the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const input = [
       [1,2,3],
       [4,5,6],
       [7,8,9]
    ];
    
 const index = 1;

const result= grab(input, index);
console.log(result);

function grab(arr, index){
   return [...input[index]]; // return copy of selected array
   // to return not a copy -> return input[index];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function grab(input, index){
   var result = [];

   for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++){
          result.push(input[index][i]);
       }
       return result;
};
```

You could learn more about slicing 2-D arrays in javascript from this source:
[1](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-multidimensional-array/)